# Question about a specific case of the argument principle for maps of circles.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Problem Statement: Let $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be a smooth map of manifolds where $S^1=\frac{[0,1]}{0~1}$, and let $f'(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ be given by the $df_t[1]_t=f'(t)[1]_{f(t)}$ at each $t\in S^1$. Let $v$ be a regular value of $f$

Rewrite the bounds of the integral using v, and conclude that 
$\int_0^1 f'(t)\ dt = n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $n$ is given by the signed sum of the pre-images of a regular value $v$.

I believe I have the proof that it's an integer. Under the mod $1$ relation $\int_0^1 f'(t)\ dt = 0$, hence the above integral (which is a real integral) must be equal to 0 mod 1, i.e, must be an integer. I didn't need any of the regular value business for this.

I'm having a little trouble on the next part. I've studied complex analysis and this is really similar to the argument principle, so I'm expecting that some how whenever I cross a value in the pre-image of $v$ while going from 0 to 1, I should get add one integer value to the integral. I know the number of pre-images of a regular value is the degree of the map $f$, and hence I intuitively expect that the result should be true, but I can't figure out how to prove that the integral increases by one each time it passes a regular value (or decreases, if the function isn't strictly monotonic).

A hint/method is preferred to the explicit answer. Thanks in advance, will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the statement "the integral increases by one each time it passes a regular value" can be made both precise and true. Integrals of continuous functions don't jump like that.

Consider the universal cover $\pi:\mathbb R\to S^1$, $\pi(x)=x\mod 1$. The composition $f\circ \pi$ is $1$-periodic, and it lifts to a smooth map $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Using this lift, you can argue along the following (mouse-over) lines:

> $F'(x)=f'(x\mod 1)$

...

> $F(1)-F(0)$ is an integer

...

> If $v$ is a regular value of $f$, then the elements of $\pi^{-1}(v)$ are regular values of $f$.

...

> $F(x)=v\mod 1$ at finitely many points $x_k\in [0,1]$ (which you can enumerate in increasing order)

...

> The value $F(x_{k+1})-F(x_{k})$ is related to the sign of $F'(x_k)$

...

> The sum of $F(x_{k+1})-F(x_{k})$ over $k$ is related to $F(1)-F(0)$